# Calling specific namespace and class using Strings

Tags: c#

I am currently writing a program in C#, this program has a folder called Classes, many subfolders named a - f, and actual cs files within that folder named aa - cc.

a-f are namespaces
aa-cc are classes.

So if I wanted to invoke a method from Classes\b\bb.cs I'd have to type every time

```
b.bb,methodName();
```

It will also generate two Strings which will decide what we are going to be executing.

```
String myType = "b";
String myClass = "bb";
String toReturn = "";
```

There are many combinations of myType and myClass so I've had to write a lot of if loops

```
if (myType.equals("b") && myClass.equals("bb") return toReturn = b.bb.myMethod();
if (myType.equals("b") && myClass.equals("aa") return toReturn = b.aa.myMethod();
```

this is quite a lot of typing and I feel like there is an easier way to do this since I already know what know what namespace I want to access and what method I want to call.

Is there any way I could do something like

```
myType.myClass.myMethod()
```

where myType is the namespace, and myClass is the class I wish to call. This would avoid me typing out ever possible combination.

Comment: What is difference between class and type? Put your code sample please

Comment: Well, you could reflect on your assembly, but that would be slow - why do you need to do this anyhow?

Comment: I'm agree, reflection is slow. But delegates can solve this problem.

Comment: [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Improved sample with delegates. Homework: add hash to store delegates in `GetDelegate` method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

using TestConsole.Data;

namespace NamespaceA
{
    public class ClassAB
    {
        public void MyMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You invoke NamespaceA.ClassAB.MyMethod");
        }

        public static void MyStaticMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You invoke NamespaceA.ClassAB.MyStaticMethod");
        }
    }
}

namespace TestConsole
{
    public delegate void DoSomethingUseful();   // same as Action delegate

    class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// create delegate
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="namespace"> namespace name </param>
        /// <param name="class"> class name </param>
        /// <param name="method"> method name </param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static DoSomethingUseful GetDelegate(string @namespace, string @class, string method)
        {
            // common argument checks
            if (@namespace == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("namespace");
            if (@class == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("class");
            if (method == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("method");

            // find class
            Type type = Type.GetType(@namespace + "." + @class);
            if (type == null) throw new Exception("type not found");

            // find method
            MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod(method);
            if (methodInfo == null) throw new Exception("method not found");

            // create the delegate
            return (DoSomethingUseful)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(DoSomethingUseful), methodInfo.IsStatic ? null : Activator.CreateInstance(type), methodInfo);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // creating delegates
            DoSomethingUseful methodA = GetDelegate("NamespaceA", "ClassAB", "MyMethod");
            DoSomethingUseful methodB = GetDelegate("NamespaceA", "ClassAB", "MyStaticMethod");

            // usage
            methodA();
            methodB();

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. In my example I provided I over simplified it, the methods return a composite object, would this still work

Comment: Yes, just change `void` to your object type (string, object, MyReturnType or so on)

Comment: The solution worked in my project. I didn't even know this was possible, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Complete code sample below.
Remember, that you should create class instance, if your class method is not static (`object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);`);

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using TestConsole.Data;

namespace NamespaceA
{
    public class ClassAB
    {
        public void MyMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You invoke NamespaceA.ClassAB.MyMethod");
        }

        public static void MyStaticMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You invoke NamespaceA.ClassAB.MyStaticMethod");
        }
    }
}

namespace TestConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Type type = Type.GetType("NamespaceA.ClassAB");
            object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            type.GetMethod("MyMethod").Invoke(instance, null);      // instance is required
            type.GetMethod("MyStaticMethod").Invoke(null, null);    // instance is not required

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `static`.

```
public static HelperClass
{
    public static void HelperMethod() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Usage (after adding a reference to your Class Library).

```
HelperClass.HelperMethod();
```